# Sequence contains no elements when updating an entity

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to update my Product entity but whenever I submit the form, it throws:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Sequence contains no elements'

This is my View :

```
@model myadminpanel.Models.product
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div class="container">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>ProductName</label>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.ProductName, new { @class = "form-control" });
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>ProductDescription</label>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.ProductDescription, new { @class = "form-control" });
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">        
            <label>Price</label>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Price, new { @class = "form-control" });
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">

            <label>Quantity</label>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Quantity, new { @class = "form-control" });

        <div class="button">        
            <button>Submit</button>        
        </div>        
    </div>
}
```

my controller Edit code is this:

```
public ActionResult ProductEdit(int id)
{
    var item = db.products.Where(x => x.ProductID == id).First();

    return View(item);


}
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ProductEdit(product model)
{
    var item = db.products.Where(x => x.ProductID == model.ProductID).First();
    item.ProductName= model.ProductName;
    item.ProductDescription = model.ProductDescription;
    item.Price = model.Price;
    item.Quantity = model.Quantity;

    db.SaveChanges();
    return View();
}
```

And this is my model of product :

```
namespace myadminpanel.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class product
    {
        public int ProductID { get; set; }
        public string ProductName { get; set; }
        public string ProductDescription { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> Price { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> Quantity { get; set; }
        public string CategoryName { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> CategoryID { get; set; }

        public virtual category category { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: `db.products.Where(x => x.ProductID == id)` returns no elements, and then First() leads to the 'Sequence contains no elements'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your form doesn't contain the id of the entity you are modifying, so this

```
var item = db.products.Where(x => x.ProductID == id).First();
```

is run as

```
var item = db.products.Where(x => x.ProductID == 0).First();
```

and there isn't any Product with ID = 0, so `First` fails to find the first match (because there isn't anything to match against).

So, add the ID as a hidden field:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
     @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ProductID)

    <div class="container">  
    ...
```